# how can I imlement muliple upload fields in drupal, each with its title and drop down category select box?

Tags: drupal, cck

Basically I want to implement the FILE UPLOAD's box shown in this link

http://laups.org/comp_2010/upload.php

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this with [CCK 3](http://drupal.org/node/484068)'s Multigroup module, [FileField](http://drupal.org/project/filefield), and CCK's Option Widgets module (or [Content Taxonomy](http://drupal.org/project/content_taxonomy) if you need to reference taxonomy terms in your drop-down menu).

CCK 3 isn't stable, but it's not particularly volatile, either.

Comment: I haven't exactly tried this, but are you sure that above mentioned functionality can be achieved.

Comment: Yes. Multigroup even has the benefit of not having to define a set number of boxes: the user can add upload boxes as needed with a simple click.

Comment: I'll try and post the results so other can also see.